# How to export the result of getDataRange() .getValues() as a json to Amazon S3 using Google App Scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, amazon-s3

I can get all the data in the active sheet doing:
`const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();   const rows = sheet   .getDataRange()   .getValues();`

Now I want to transform this array of arrays in key-value json and then send it to a S3 bucket.
On Google API Doc and App Script Doc I can't find nothing about it.

I am using App Scripts.

Comment: what are the keys?

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/liddiard/google-sheet-s3 and https://github.com/liddiard/google-sheet-s3/blob/master/Code.gs

Answer (score 0):

To transform your data in a json, try

```
function table2json() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('YourSheetName');
  var [headers, ...rows] = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var items = []
  rows.forEach(function(r) {
    var obj={}
    r.forEach(function (c, j) {
      obj[headers[j]] = c
    })
    items.push(obj)
  })
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(items))
}
```

Format the sheet so that the first row contains the keys

[image]